# Emit and Catch event in Angular components

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I created the following Angular 7 accordion component [SlackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mk-angular-accordion-xtshah):

```
export class AccordionComponent {

  @ContentChildren(PanelComponent) panels: QueryList<PanelComponent>;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.panels.forEach((panel) => {panel.active = false;});
  }

  onReset(panel: PanelComponent) {
    this.panels.toArray().forEach(panel => panel.active = false);
  }

}
```

The PanelComponent is the following:

```
export class PanelComponent {

  @Input() active: boolean;
  @Input() title: string;

  @Output() reset: EventEmitter<PanelComponent> = new EventEmitter();

  toggle() {
    this.active = !this.active;
    if (this.active)
      this.reset.emit(this);
  }

}
```

When I open a Panel I need to close all other panels ...

My idea to solve this is to:

1. Emit event in toggle function when setting `active = true`;
   I suppose I need to pass the panel itself in the event?
2. Catch that event in Accordion component.
   And with the panel passed in the event close all other panels.

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can catch the output event in your `accordion.component` and `subscribe` to it.

**PanelComponent**

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'panel',
  templateUrl: './panel.component.html'
})

export class PanelComponent {

  @Input() active: boolean;
  @Input() title: string;

  @Output() activate = new EventEmitter();

  toggle() {
    this.active = !this.active;
    if (this.active) {
      this.activate.emit();
    }   
  }

}
```

**AccordionComponent**

```
import { Component, ContentChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';

import { Subject } from 'rxjs'
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators'

import { PanelComponent } from './panel.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'accordion',
  templateUrl: './accordion.component.html'
})

export class AccordionComponent {

  @ContentChildren(PanelComponent) panels: QueryList<PanelComponent>;

  destroy$ = new Subject<boolean>();

  ngAfterContentInit() {

    this.panels.forEach((panel) => {
      panel.active = false;
      panel.activate.pipe(
        takeUntil(this.destroy$)
      ).subscribe(() => {
        this.closeAllButPanel(panel);
      })
    });

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next(true);
    this.destroy$.unsubscribe();
  }

  closeAllButPanel(panelToIgnore: PanelComponent) {
    this.panels.filter(p => p!==panelToIgnore).forEach(panel => panel.active = false);
  }

}
```